# Graphql Mysql - Get rows from a table in JSON Format

Tags: node.js, graphql, node-postgres, typegraphql

I'm working on Backend with [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/docs/enums.html) and [NodePostGres](https://node-postgres.com/).
User will pass database id and table name. I need to send data in JSON Format.

I have tried below code but it doesn't return anything nor does it throw any error.

**Service:**

```
import { Service } from 'typedi'
import { Client } from 'pg'

import { databases } from './db'
import { Payload } from './models'

@Service()
export class PayloadService {
  fetchPayload(id: number, tableName: string): Payload {
    const databaseCredentials = databases.find((d) => d.id && +d.id === id)

    if (!databaseCredentials) throw new Error('Invalid ID!')

    const client = new Client({
      host: databaseCredentials.host,
      port: +(databaseCredentials.port || 5432),
      user: databaseCredentials.username,
      password: databaseCredentials.password,
      database: databaseCredentials.database,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    })

    console.log('before client')

    client.query("select * from pg_tables where schemaname='public'", (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
      } else {
        console.log(res.rows[0])
      }
      console.log(`callback`)
    })

    console.log('after client')
    return {
      id,
      data: [],
    }
  }
}
```

**Resolver:**

```
import { Arg, Query, Resolver } from 'type-graphql'
import { Inject } from 'typedi'

import { Payload } from './models'
import { PayloadService } from './services'

@Resolver(Payload)
export class PayloadResolver {
  @Inject()
  private PayloadService: PayloadService

  @Query((returns) => Payload)
  payload(@Arg('databaseId') databaseId: number, @Arg('tableName') tableName: string) {
    return this.PayloadService.fetchPayload(databaseId, tableName)
  }
}
```

Comment: start with return hardcoded value (matching [unknown] query return type - Payload) from resolver

Comment: @xadm That is already there and working fine. Check return statement. Only the query is not being executed.

Comment: 'only' graphql server not working? start with basic server config, resolver returning string only?